# Get Firefox working on Heroku app: XPCOMGlueLoad error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, heroku, firefox

I am trying to get Firefox working on Heroku. My recent build succeeded but some problems:

1. 'Application error' when trying to access the app's URL ('check your logs at `heroku logs --tail`').
2. `heroku logs --tail` error:

   `2021-05-07T02:37:38.937508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=www.mysite.com request_id=be150e6e-295d-4121-a90a-gh8519sa174 fwd="<ipaddress>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http`
   `2021-05-07T02:37:39.405719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.mysite.com request_id=6caff434-1hfa-4gqb-a3c3-7209sh2k0cf9 fwd="<ipaddress>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http`
3. The typical solution for the above H14 error is to scale the dynos up:

   `➜  myapp git:(master) ✗ heroku ps:scale web=1`
   `Scaling dynos... !`
    `▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).`
4. `heroku console` error:

   `XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /app/vendor/firefox/libmozgtk.so:`
   `libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`
   `Couldn't load XPCOM.`

The heroku push looked like:

```
➜  myapp git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master                                           
Enumerating objects: 2, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 349 bytes | 349.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: http://github.com/buitron/firefox-buildpack
remote: -----> firefox app detected
remote: -----> Extracting Firefox binaries to /tmp/build_1f06c3e2/vendor/firefox
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 81.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v21
remote:        https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
```

I have tried the following buildpacks so far with NO changes in result:

1. heroku-integrated-firefox-geckodriver
2. buitron's firefox-buildpack

My app only needs this code in one place. Here is that code:

```
require 'webdrivers/geckodriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'fileutils'
Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :info

# SET UP SELENIUM
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.download.dir'] = download_dir
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = ('application/pdf, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv')
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(profile: profile, args: ['-headless'])
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, options: options

driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10 # seconds
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)

driver.get "https://theurl.com"

...traverse website...
driver.quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buitron buildpack has some issues, including a long-running unfixed bug due to a missing semi-colon.

The current recommendation is to use [evosystem-jp's buildpack](https://github.com/evosystem-jp/heroku-buildpack-firefox). I got it working by cloning the buildpack and updating to the latest versions of Firefox and Geckodriver.